# AWS SES "Email address is not verified." for VERIFIED and PRODUCTION (not sandbox) email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

As I said in the topic, I am not able to send email through AWS SES.

The email is verified (even the domain is verified) and the environment is not sandbox.

A little background:

1. Last year I configured AWS SES and verified a gmail account (something like myapp_noreply@gmail.com). It worked like a charm.
2. Now, we are migrating to a more professional approach and I wanted to change that email address to our own domain.
3. So I added and verified my domain and my email address (something like contact@myapp.com) in the same region (East 1).
4. Both, domain and email address, are verified and I requested more quota to get out of sandbox environment. Its ok now.
5. I changed my code to send from that new email address but all I can get is "Email address is not verified."

PS.: I even verified a third email (my personal gmail account) and I get "Email address is not verified." as well.

In other words: It's like AWS is not allowing me to add new email addresses.

Do I have to create new SMTP credentials?

My code, for clarification:

```
            var client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", 587);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("XXX", "XXX"); 


            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();

            message.To.Add(destinatario);
            message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myemail@mycompany.com");
            message.Subject = titulo;
            message.Body = corpo;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            client.Send(message);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SES is a regional service, so here's a possibility I've seen before: Did you perhaps do all this verification and setup with your console set to "Oregon" (us-west-2) even though your code is using "us-east-1" (Northern Virginia)?

Comment: I am using just east-1 for every email address I verified

Comment: Right, but, to confirm... are you using the correct region in the console?  You may have inadvertently verified the addresses and gained production access in a different region.

Comment: have you checked that everything looks right in SES Console?

Comment: Yes. I can even send Test Emails in the SES Console to non verified email addresses.
I can see the 3 email addresses I added (the first one that works, the second with my own domain that doesnt work and the third one, my personal, which doesnt workd either) at the same region in SES console.

I walked through all 3 available regions in SES console just to be sure and theres no email address in any other region besides east-1

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? @HugoRamos